# Gatsby throws error on build only - Expected property "1" of type BigInteger, got n

Tags: cryptography, gatsby, biginteger

I am making a cryptographic signature.
To this end, I am using the following libraries 'bigi', 'bs58', 'ecdsa', 'pbkdf2-sha256', and 'crypto'.

When on the development environment, there are no issues.

When running gatsby build, I am getting this error

{"message":"Expected property "1" of type BigInteger, got n","__property":1,"__type":"BigInteger","__value":{"0":5218218,"1":6291014,"2":34656281,"3":1776116,"4":53518743,"5":10808093,"6":62725491,"7":63913863,"8":50275223,"9":1979384,"t":10,"s":0},"__valueTypeName":"n"}

For what I read, there is a polyfill problem on uglifying the code in one of the libraries. I tried `gatsby build --noUglify` but it didn't solve the problem.

I am really new to this, so I am at loss

Edit: can this may have anything to do with locally using node and in the server nginx?